# Saving image with Japanese text

Tags: php, image, text, unicode

I have installed --enable-gd-jis-conv=shared and --enable-mbstring=shared, but I still can't seem to get Japanese text saved into an image using a font file.

If I change "英雄時代" to some english text, the image is created correctly with the english characters of the Japanese font, however with Japanese text I get weird squares and other things.

```
public function makeJapaneseCharacter($font="static/JFONT.TTF", $W=200, $H=20, $X=0, $Y=0, $fsize=18, $color=array(0x0,0x0,0x0), $bgcolor=array(0xFF,0xFF,0xFF))
{        
$this->im = @imagecreate($W, $H)
or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");

$background_color = imagecolorallocate($this->im, $bgcolor[0], $bgcolor[1], $bgcolor[2]); //RGB color background.
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($this->im, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2]);            //RGB color text.

imagettftext($this->im, $fsize, $X, $Y, $fsize, $text_color, $font, mb_convert_encoding('英雄時代', 'SJIS', 'UTF-8'));
$this->saveAsPng("jchar", "static/");
}


public function saveAsPng($fileName, $location= null)
{        

    $_fileName = $fileName.".png";
    $_fileName = is_null($location)?$_fileName:$location.$_fileName;
    return imagepng($this->im, $_fileName);        
}
```

Any help would be great appreciated,
Nicholas.

Answer (score 0):

try writing `L'英雄時代'` instead of `'英雄時代'`. I don't know what language you are using but that's what you'd have to do in C.

Answer (score 0):

```
imagettftext($this->im, 58, 0, 50, 100,
    $text_color, $font,
    mb_convert_encoding('佳人', 'UTF8', 'UTF-8'));
```

The key has been found.